# how to build dynamic query to sql database in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I would like to fill combobox by using dynamic query. To do this, it was created external class called **sqlcnn**. This class defines connection to sql databases and it works properly. Here below code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class sqlcnn

```
Public cnn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress...)
Public Command As SqlCommand
Public txt() As String
Public i As Integer

Public Sub execute_command(ByVal query As String)

    Try
        cnn.Open()

        Command = New SqlCommand(query, cnn)

        Dim readerr = Command.ExecuteReader

        ReDim txt(readerr.FieldCount - 1)

        While readerr.Read


            For i = 0 To readerr.FieldCount - 1
                txt(i) = readerr.Item(i)

            Next i


        End While

        MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
    End Try


End Sub
```

End Class

If I modify the code above by adding into for loop one line more:

```
 For i = 0 To readerr.FieldCount - 1
                txt(i) = readerr.Item(i)
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(txt(i))

            Next i
```

I can fill immediately the combobox, without any problem.

The problem is, when I try to fill combobox from main class called Form1.
This class defines one combobox1 and one button. Here below the code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sql As New sqlcnn
Dim i As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Sql.execute_command("select Car from shopcars")

    For i = 0 To (Sqlpol.txt.Length - 1)

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Sqlpol.txt(i))

    Next i


End Sub
```

End class

The result is that, inside the combobox we can see only last item of my database. Completely, I don't have idea how to build properly for loop.
I'm grateful for the help.

thanks!

Comment: if you are new and want faster development use pocoorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt` is a one-dimensional array. Each iteration of `While` you are overwriting txt index 0 through index `readerr.FieldCount`. That is why it always contains the data from the last row.
You need a different data structure that supports many rows. There are many options. I would recommend a DataTable because you can then bind it to  your ComboBox instead of adding items in a loop.